# Sub package imports with python

Tags: python, adapter, python-import, circular-dependency

I am new to python, but very experienced with PHP and JavaScript and fairly familiar with Java (I use each nearly every day). I have used python for scripts, but have never tried a large, complex project until now.

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the way python handles package imports. I have search and read several other answers, but still can't get my specific case to work.  I would imagine my error is due to bad or non-pythonic design, but I feel like what I'm doing is such a common practice in other languages I have worked with, that it should be simple.

I have the following directory tree

```
+ project (project directory)
    + replicator (source directory)
        + adapters
            - __init__.py 
            - wwf_score.py
            - other_adpater.py (there will be many adapter modules in this package)
        - sources.py
        - __init__.py (empty init for replicator)
```

I am looking for a modular design where I can instantiate specific adapters on the fly. Those adapters extend an `abc.ABC` abstract class in `adapters.__init__` which also holds some common utilities for adapters.

Pretty simple.

The issue is that the individual adapter modules need to reference some definitions in `replicator.sources`. Specifically two classes. What is happening is that each adapter grabs data from a third party and hydrates a `RawSource` object, which is defined in `replicator.sources`

**wwf_score.py**

```
import replicator.adapters as adapters
import replicator.sources as sources

@adapters.source_adapter
class WWFScoreAdapter(adapters.AbstractAdapter):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = sources.RawData(data)
```

This throws an error that `AttributeError: module 'replicator' has no attribute 'adapters'`

I have tried adding an import to `replicators.__init__`, and have tried relative imports and several other things.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all!

**EDIT**

It appears my real problem is in a specific adapter importing something from the `adapters.__init__` or in (somehow) actually registering the `adapters` package with the `replicator`. I *can* import from `replicator.sources` inside `wwf_score.py`, it appears. Maybe that helps.

**EDIT** Updated for clarity and readability.

Comment: can you 1) `import replicator` and 2) `print(replicator.__file__)` ?

Comment: I had to strip some code, but I did print that inside wwf_score and got the path for `replicator.__init__` (stripped code because dependencies couldn't be resolved)

Comment: btw `other_adpater`: typo?

Comment: @9000, that's something I hadn't considered. I'm actually *running* this from a `bin/script.py` file that is importing and executing various things. For clarity, I'm going to edit my question to get rid of the repeated `replicator`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that wasn't a typo. It was to convey that there will be several adapters for different sources in that package.

Comment: Errors like the one you got usually mean you have circular imports.  In Python2, the import machinery is such that when you do have circular imports, only absolute imports (without `as`) will work without Import or Attribute errors (e.g. `import replicator.adapters`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution, but would still be open to thoughts on better design**

As I expected, my issue was in poor design and not understanding imports. I was trying to do actual definitions inside some of the `__init__` files, and referencing those definitions outside the package. It led to spaghetti code. I ended up solving this problem by doing two things:

**1. Smaller, clearer modules**
I removed all the definitions from the `__init__` files and gave them their own modules. One of these included a decorator that was a callable class bound to an attribute that wasn't available outside the **init** file. I'm not sure exactly how, but I am sure that was muddying things a lot.

My new structure looks like this (if anyone cares)

```
+ project
    + bin
        - replicator.py (script that uses the rest)
    + replicator
        + adapters
            - __init__.py (blank except to import modules)
            - contracts.py (pulled from init, includes Abstract)
            - registry.py (has a class decorator bound to attribute)
            - wwf_score.py (class that extends Abstract)
            - other_adapter.py (another class that extends Abstract)
        - sources.py (the same, just some dtos)
        - __init__.py (empty except for imports)
```

**2. I used all relative imports inside the package**
So, my `wwf_score.py` imports look like

```
from . import contracts
from . import registry
from .. import sources
```

My `bin/replicator.py` file can reference things via

```
import replicator.adapters as adapters
import replicator.sources as sources
```

And all is well.

I hope this helps someone in the future. I'm free to answer questions about my setup and what I found.

Like I said, part of my problem is that I was doing something else complicated -- a class-based decorator that decorated a class. This was used to register all my individual adapters with a registry (and a key), so I could use a factory to create them.

Thanks.